# MineField with Js

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a minefield game with javascript.

When I click on **clear ro**w it gives "passed" but sometimes "died" too or clicking on **mined row** gives sometimes "passed". It's supposed to give only "passed" with clear and "died" with mined row.

I can't figure out the reason..

Could you see it?

Here is my code so far:

```
  var level = 9;

   // create the table
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  var tbl = document.createElement("table");
  tbl.setAttribute('id', 'myTable');
  var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");



   //Create 2d table with mined/clear
  for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
      var row = document.createElement("tr");
      document.write("<br/>");

      for (var x = 1; x <= 10; x++) {
          var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);

          if (j <= 15) {
              j = "mined";
          } else {
              j = "clear";
          }
          var cell = document.createElement("td");
          var cellText = document.createTextNode(j + "");
          cell.appendChild(cellText);
          row.appendChild(cell);

      }
      tblBody.appendChild(row);
  }
  tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
  body.appendChild(tbl);
  tbl.setAttribute("border", "1");


   //Check which row is clicked

  window.onload = addRowHandlers;

  function addRowHandlers() {
      var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
      var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("td");
      for (p = 0; p < rows.length; p++) {
          var currentRow = table.rows[p];
          var createClickHandler = function (row) {
              return function () {
                  var cell = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
                  var id = cell.innerHTML;
                  if (id == "mined") {
                      alert("Died");
                  } else {
                      alert("Passed!");
                  }
              };
          }

          currentRow.onclick = createClickHandler(currentRow);
      }
  }
```

JSFiddle Here:
http://jsfiddle.net/blowsie/ykuyE/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Am I missing something? I pasted your code into JSfiddle, and nothing works?

Comment: Also naming a text / html value `id` is a really bad idea and really confusing.

Comment: Here is one JS-only version of MineSweeper, if you want to take a closer look: http://vsego.org/minesweeper/

Comment: Blowsie 
Thnx for the comment but would you maybe tell then me how I can better create an id with js for a table? 

VedranŠego  
Thnx for the source! I'll get some tips here..

Comment: vsego.org/minesweeper looks little bit overwhelming for me.. I thought that project can be good for new starter. But appearently It's a bit more complicated than I thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its' this line, which causes the faulty behaviour: `var cell = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[1];` Everytime a click is made, the `[1]` selects the 2nd cell of a column, no matter which cell was actually clicked.

I modified your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ykuyE/1
The onclick handler is now applied to the individual cell directly, when the table is created.

```
cell.onclick = function() {
    if (this.innerHTML == "mined") {
        alert("Died");
    } else {
        alert("Passed!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yey! Thank you very much for your time! I got it!